# Are typed/generic aspects worth the effort?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, postsharp

I've done a little research on typed/generic aspects. An important fact about aspects is obliviousness. So the concerns of the aspects should be orthogonal to the domain concerns. Nevertheless there are investigations to make AspectJ type safe (StrongAspectJ) / introduce per-type aspects using generics. One paper mentioned an implementation of the Flyweight pattern as an aspect. Now I'm wondering if there are more use cases for generic aspects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostSharp is weakly typed, i.e. the advices see arguments and return values as 'objects'. There is some support for generic aspects in PostSharp (aspects can be generic classes), but it is not very useful since the advises are weakly typed.

Note that behind the cover, the glue code generated by PostSharp is strongly typed. But everything is downcast to an object when exposed to aspect code.

I'm considering implementing strongly-typed advised in a next version of PostSharp, possible with support of generic arguments. The reason would be run-time performance, because boxing of value types into an object brings a considerable performance overhead. Note that generics are implemented differently in .NET than in Java, so the point may need to be discussed differently on both platforms.

Feel free to contact me personally if you need any help for your thesis.

Comment: Good point about the difference between generics .NET and Java.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-generating some of the boilerplate to [make a class callable via RMI](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.2146&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is another use case. That example implements some around advice for a bunch of methods.

```
pointcut callsToServer(Type T):
    call(public T Server.*(..)) && this(Client)
T around(Type T): callsToServer(T) {
    T obj = null;
    try {
        obj = proceed();
    } catch (java.rmi.RemoteException ex) {}
    return obj;
}
```

Generics allow you to say "we are going to return an object of the same type the method signature says". This is true, of course, if we just return the object. We might be able to do something similar with "after throwing" advice, but we wouldn't be able to manipulate the return value to translate a RemoteException into a null return value.

Comment: What do you mean by *We might be able to do something similar with "after throwing" advice, but we wouldn't be able to manipulate the return value to translate a RemoteException into a null return value.* ? I don't have much experience with AspectJ, I'm more familiar with PostSharp, which is a AOP framework for C#. Nevertheless, I thought AspectJ is the tag to go, because it is the leader in AOP research.

Comment: The point was that AspectJ can let you ignore the return value in advice that doesn't care about it. In those cases, there would be no need for a generic type to hold the return value. "After throwing" is advice that only is applied when an exception is being thrown, so there is no return value. But if you want to manipulate the return value, as this code does, you need to be able to hold it in a variable. And if the pointcut hits multiple join points which have different return types you will benefit from a generic parameter. Returning null instead of throwing an exception is one such case.

Comment: Agree with that. On the other hand, there are numerous AOP implementations that use another approach. You'll get an `IInvocation` object that contains arguments, and the return value. So there is no `return` in an advice, except you want to exit it earlier. The fields you can set on the `IInvocation` object are of type `object`. As a consequence, you can hardly speak of type-safety. In my opinion your RMI example (as well as my flyweight!) are some kind of misuse of AOP. Without knowing AOP I would use the factory pattern for both of them. Even with AOP, I would say it's the better choice.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong. I'm doing researches for my master thesis, and that's the reason why I'm so skeptical. :)

Comment: IInvocation could become IInvocation<V> where V is the return type. I don't think you can necessarily say the examples are misuses of AOP. Don't forget about monkey patching. One major use of AOP is changing the behavior of code you don't control. In that case both examples are perfectly valid.